# Rotate 1 degree every millisecond?

Tags: javascript

I wish to make it so when the function Rotate() is called, it rotates the image 1 degree every milisecond

This code is not working, I don't see any syntax errors

This is my code, thanks

```
    <script>
        var Roation = 0;

        function Rotate() {
            setInterval(function() {
                Rotation = Rotation + 1;
                document.getElementById("Test").style.transform = "rotate("+Rotation+"deg)";
                document.getElementById("Test").style.msTransform = "rotate("+Rotation+"deg)";
                document.getElementById("Test").style.webkitTransform = "rotate("+Rotation+"deg)";

            }, 1)
        }
    </script>
<body>
<a href="javascript:Rotate()"><img src="http://www.industus.com/test/wat1.png" id="Test"></a>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want 1000fps? That is insane. I don't think any display device can display that.

Comment: Open your developer console. That's how you find typos in your variables.

Comment: Yeah, 1000 fps is going to be hell on the cpu. Why not 10 degrees every 100ms?

Comment: As @sawa implies, a 1ms timer is too fast--try 17ms.  The display typically refreshes at roughly every 16ms so at best, you're rotating 16 times before the screen can refresh and at worst you will start stacking up callbacks to setInterval which will eventually freeze the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: you have a misspelling on the second line:

```
var Roation = 0;
```

should be

```
var Rotation = 0;
```

Second: you need to put your `<script>` tag inside the `<head>` tag (or even the `<body>` tag, but don't leave it outside both.)